# C++ initialize static constexpr from non-type parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, c++-templates

I would like to develop a compile-time evaluation for a static constexpr struct member. However, despite my efforts, I have been unable to get the code to function correctly.

The following code will explain what I want better.

```cpp
struct s1 {
    int a;
};

template <class T>
struct var {
    const char* name;
    int T::*offset;
};

constexpr int sum(auto&&... n)
{
    return (n + ...);
}

template <var... Ts>
struct A {
    int arg1;

    static constexpr auto value = sum((int)Ts.offset...);
};

template <int... Ts>
struct B {
    int arg1;

    static constexpr auto value = sum(Ts...);
};
```

And this is how I'm reference it:

```cpp
auto Works      = B<1, 2, 3>::value;  // works == 6
auto Help       = A<{"a", &s1::a}>::value;
```

My final goal is to call the 3rd party function `constexpr auto unknown(auto&&... args)` function instead of `sum`, therefore I will need to expand my args as follow:

```cpp
template <var... Ts>
struct C {
    int arg1;

    static constexpr auto value = unknown(Ts.name, Ts.offset ...);
};
```

That way it will expand to:

```cpp
static constexpr auto value = unknown("a", &s1::a, "b", &s1::b ...);
```

Comment: It is not possible to cast a pointer-to-member to an integer type, nor is it possible to add up such member pointers.

Comment: I assume `template <var... Ts>` is a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to take each `var` in the `Ts` pack, create a `std::tuple<const char*, int T::*>`, then [`tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) these 2-tuples together, which you can [`apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to your `unknown` function:

```cpp
    // static constexpr auto value = unknown(Ts.name, Ts.offset ...);
    static constexpr auto value = std::apply(
        [](auto... args) { return unknown(args...); },
        std::tuple_cat(std::tuple(Ts.name, Ts.offset)...)
    );
```

---

And since you can't directly store a pointer to a string literal in a non-type template parameter, store the name directly in `var` and this should compile:

```cpp
template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct var {
    const char name[N];
    int T::*offset;
};
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/j1scWvhrx

Comment: Thank you for the professional and quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> A<{"a", &s1::a}>
> ```

You *cannot* use a string literal as a template parameter. Ever. Any attempt to smuggle a pointer to a string literal through a template parameter will fail.

If you want to pass a string to a template parameter, you need to make it into an array of characters, not a pointer.